# Equations and math in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I just don't know how to explain what I need. I'm not looking for any codes, but just tutorial and direction to get to where I need to be.

Example: I have numbers in a csv file, a and b are in different columns:

```
header1,header2
a,b
a1,b1
a2,b2
a3,b3
a4,b4
a5,b5
a6,b6
```

so how would i create something like

```
[a(b)+a1(b1)+a2(b2)...a6(b6)] /(divided by) [sum of (all b values)]
```

ok so I know how to code the denominator by using pandas, but how would I code the numerator?

What is this process called, and where can I find a tutorial for it?

Comment: is `a(b)` a times b?

Comment: The numerator of your intended expression is called the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the two column vectors. I don't quite recognize the overall expression. Note that it risks division by zero. Dot product is [supported in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dot.html#pandas.Series.dot).

Comment: no, you have to a* b.....all the way to a6*b6 and add them all up

Comment: re the second half of your question, im afraid that is a very broad topic, and tough to recommend a single resource for. (not to mention, resource recommendations are off topic on SO). Having said that, you're essentially looking to learn array operations. [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/data-manipulation-visualisation-r-python/tutorial-data-manipulation-numpy-pandas-python/tutorial/) can be a start. Regardless though, read other questions on SO, and you'll learn it over time. don't expect to learn it overnight.

Comment: my bad, a(b) means a times b, or a*b

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best method but should work. You can create a new column in pandas which is product of a*b

```
df['product'] = df['a']*df['b']
```

You can then simply user `sum()` to get sum of column b and column product and then divide the product by b:

```
ans = df['product'].sum() / df['b'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best method to use, but you could use **list comprehensions** along with the `zip()` function. With these two, you can get the nominator like this:

```
[a*b for a, b in zip(df['header1'], df['header2'])]
```

[Chapter 3](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2012/docs/diveintopython3/comprehensions.html) of [Dive into Python 3](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2012/docs/diveintopython3/index.html) has more on list comprehensions. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is the documentation on `zip()` and [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-use-pythons-enumerate-and-zip-to/) a few examples of its usage.